# Appending to a Multidimensional Array?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm switching to swift.  While building an app I found myself with the following issue; I can't figure out a better way to do this, but so far it works but I would really like to know if this is the proper way to do it or not, if so how can it be better?

Let's say we have the following empty array:

```
 var users:[[String:String]] = []
```

After that there is some code and finally we got the important part.

```
        if resultSet != nil{
            while resultSet.next(){
                 var single_user = [
                    "userID": resultSet.stringForColumn(userid) as String,
                    "username": resultSet.stringForColumn(firstname) as String,
                    "userlastname": resultSet.stringForColumn(lastname) as String,
                    "userlastupdate": resultSet.stringForColumn(lastupdate) as String
                 ]
                users.append(single_user)

            }
        }
```

From there I do get the right values:

[image]

But like I said, is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Its OK.  Personally I would create a `User` struct with appropriate properties and store that rather than storing a dictionary.

Comment: By the way, it is only a single-dimension array of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks. yeah that is a great idea thanks @Paulw11